# how to get an AdWords developer token

Tags: api, google-ads-api

i developed a SEO web application: it gets the SERP position for a list of keywords and calculates the visibility index of a site using many parameters.
one of these parameters is the average local monthly searches from AdWords, so i'd like to use the AdWords API to get search volumes when i need it.
my company has an MCC account, so i requested a developer token, explaining in depth how i will have used it, but the AdWords API Review team refused to give me the token:

> As stated in the AdWords API terms and conditions, "The AdWords APIs
>   are a feature of the Google AdWords program". However, your company
>   does not appear to be using the AdWords APIs in connection with the
>   Google AdWords program which we consider to be a violation of the API
>   terms and conditions.

i'd like to know how other software houses, like Caphyon - Advanced Web Ranking, got their token.
any help?

Answer (score 0):

I Think what Google are saying is that if you're not a paying AdWords customer then you can't use the API. The Software house that you mentioned almost certainly have AdWords accounts. In short they're giving Google money.

Why not create an AdWords account and base your app on it?

Comment: thanks, but as i stated in my question, i not only have an adwords account, but i have (ok, the company i work for has) an MCC managing big budget active campaigns. nevertheless google team answered that way.

Answer (score 0):

**How To Get A Google AdWords API Developer Token**

To use AdWords API to obtain Search Volume statistics, you need to have AdWords API's "[Standard Access](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/access-levels#standard_access)" and must meet [RMF requirements](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/requirements). Once you do, you can get a developer token to call the API with.

**What Are RMF Requirements?**

RMF requirements basically requires that **your app allow users to manage their AdWords campaigns through it**. Essentially, it requires that your app be geared towards contributing to AdWords's bottom line. To be approved, you need to submit documentation (possibly a wireframe of your app) to show how it allows your users to manage their AdWords campaigns.

**A Much Easier Way, Use A Third-Party**

If all you want is Search Volume statistics, there is a much easier way. **You can simply get it from a third-party** who can pull data from Google updated monthly such as [GrepWords](http://www.grepwords.com/). This is where [Moz](https://moz.com/explorer) gets their data (source: I spoke with their data guy). They also combine it with clickstream data to generate their search volume predictions which even rivals Google's own predictions.

**Some Industry Tools And Their Data Sources**

- **[SEMRush](https://www.semrush.com/api-analytics/#phrase_all)** uses an **algorithm** to estimate their traffic (source: spoke with them at a conference in 2016).
- **[ahrefs](http://help.ahrefs.com/ahrefs-metrics/where-does-your-search-volume-data-for-keywords-come-from)** uses a **third party** to get **click stream data** and pairs it with **data from Google**
- **[MOZ](https://moz.com/explorer)** uses a **third party** to get their **Google data** and **click stream data** (source: spoke with team).
- **[KWFinder](https://kwfinder.com/alternative-to-keyword-planner.html)** reports that their **data is the same as Google** Keyword Planner.
- **[Twinword Ideas](https://www.twinword.com/ideas/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=howtogetanadwordsdevelopertoken&utm_content=twinwordideas)** **actually** gets their data **directly from Google** (source: I work there).